# Suppose that a $3\times 3$ matrix $M$ has an eigenspace of dimension $3$. Prove that $M$ is a diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I go about this? I realise that having dimension 3 means that the solution to $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf b = \mathbf 0$ has 3 free parameters, which would in turn mean that $(A-\lambda I)$ is the zero matrix, so $A = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda & 0 & 0\\0 & \lambda & 0\\0 & 0 & \lambda\end{bmatrix}$, but the first part of that argument is a bit too heuristic. How would I prove it formally?

Comment: Every vector is an eigenvector of $A$ with  common eigenvalue $\lambda$; in particular, the unit vectors are. So...

Comment: @Kaster, No, I meant diagonal. A 3x3 diagonalisable matrix could have 3 corresponding eigenspaces each of dimension 1.

Comment: Here's a hint: What are the three dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$? (Or $\mathbb{F}^3$ for any non-trivial field $\mathbb{F}$?)

Comment: @David Then let $P = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Hence $A = PDP^{-1} = IDI = D$. Hence A is diagonal?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But I meant to imply that $Ae_i=\lambda e_i$ for each $i=1,2,3$. But $Ae_i$ is the $i$th column of $A$. The result follows directly.

Comment: Cool, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Imagine you have three linearly independent (column) eigenvectors for $\lambda$, and put them into the columns of a matrix $B$, which is necessarily nonsingular. Then $AB=B(\lambda I_3)=(\lambda I_3)B$.

Can you see how to conclude this, remembering that $B$ has an inverse?

---

In general, no matter what the eigenvalues are, you can use this observation to find a matrix $B$ such that $AB=BD$ where $D$ has the eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal, and is zero elsewhere. But unless all the eigenvalues are the same, you can't always conclude that $BD$ and $DB$ are the same. They are quite often different. Can you see why?

Comment: This seems like an unnecessarily convoluted way to approach this problem.

Comment: +1: I think this is a reasonable approach?

Comment: Dear @TomOldfield : That assessment seems rather overblown considering the solution is two sentences containing two simple steps, one of which is commonly used when analyzing such problems. I'm sorry you felt strongly enough about it to memorialize in a comment :(

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the vote of confidence!

Comment: @rschwieb I'm sorry, I didn't mean any offence. It's not the length that bothered me, just that the approach seemed a little in-depth for what seemed like an elementary question from someone with not that much working knowledge of linear-algebra. The process of finding three arbitrary linearly independent eigenvectors and then knowing that their matrix is non-singular seems more challenging to a beginner than simply saying "The three usual basis vectors are eigenvectors, so..." Again, no offence meant!

Comment: Dear @TomOldfield None taken then :) IMO, going that far in depth carries a bit of useful thinking for the beginner about abstract thinking. I'd like to point out that even though computing eigenvectors is hard, in this solution you just need to imagine that you have them, and there is no need to compute them. (In fact, I think that's valuable enough to add into the post.)

Answer (score 1):

If any matrix $B$ satisfies $B v_k = 0$ for a basis $v_k$, then $B=0$.

In this case, the dimension of the space is $3$ and the dimension of the eigenspace is $3$, hence we have $(A-\lambda I)v_k = 0$ on a basis $v_k$, hence
$A = \lambda I$ as required.

Comment: This doesn't seem any easier to prove than the original statement, to me at least...

Comment: @TomOldfield: It was just showing the OP how to formalize the answer.

Comment: I suppose. But the OP's attempt talked about parameters, which is completely different in spirit to this approach, so I think that, in a sense, this isn't formalising their answer as much as providing a different one. This is all fine, but the "different" answer looks more convoluted than other possible "different" answers. No offence meant...

Comment: @TomOldfield: None taken! I suppose I view 'free parameters' as synonymous with dimensions...

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Note that $A$ can be diagonalized $\Longleftrightarrow$ $A$'s algebraic multiplicity $=$ $A$'s geometric multiplicity. And according to the definition of similarity, $A$ itself is also a diagonal matrix.

The intuition behind the theorem is that there is no need to resort to Jordan chain because there are "enough" eigenvectors. And since there is no Jordan chain, the matrix can be diagonalized.

Comment: The eigenvalues are 3, 2 and 1, so we have three 1-dimensional eigenspaces, not one 3-dimensional eigenspace, which was my question. I can't why your answer is relevant, could you explain please?

Comment: @user46080 OK, I've messed up with _eigenspace_ and the space spanned by _eigenvectors_. And I've updated my answer. If you feel it somehow helpful, you can cancel the downvote.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote dood!

Comment: @user46080 Well, OK, calm...